# Is this Session::init() code secure?

Tags: php, session

This is the `init()` method in my session class:

```
public static function init() {
    $bSecure = true;
    $bHttpOnly = true;

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie( 
        'sid', 
        session_id(),  
        $cookieParams['lifetime'],  
        $cookieParams['path'],  
        $cookieParams['domain'],  
        $bSecure,  
        $bHttpOnly 
    );

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    if (!isset($_SESSION['valid_sess'])) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }

    $_SESSION['valid_sess'] = true;
}
```

Is this secure? I've already got an SSl certificate

Comment: Secure from what? What kind of information are you dealing with, bank data?

Comment: @RPM The only things I store in it are the user id and if the user is logged in

Comment: well it's gonna be useless if you store the session_id in a cookie and then regenerate a new ID afterwards... Otherwise... it semms all good.

Comment: The weird thing is that this code works o.0 but is it secure?

Comment: Yes it will work now, but will have a problem when you're re-reading the cookie. yes it seems secure. I can't see any probs right now. But you can improve the code a bit.

Comment: How can I improve it? And do you mean with re-reading getting `$_SESSION` variables? That's working fine for me.